# Why does weakproxy not always preserve equivalence in python?

Tags: python, weak-references

MySQLDb uses weak proxy to prevent circular dependencies between cursors and connections.

But you would expect from the documentation on weakref that you could still tests for equivalence. Yet:

```
In [36]: interactive.cursor.connection.thread_id()
Out[36]: 4267758

In [37]: interactive.web_logic.conns.primary.thread_id()
Out[37]: 4267758

In [38]: interactive.cursor.connection == interactive.web_logic.conns.primary
Out[38]: False

In [39]: interactive.cursor.connection
Out[39]: <weakproxy at 0x3881c60 to Connection at 0x94c010>

In [40]: interactive.web_logic.conns.primary
Out[40]: <_mysql.connection open to 'xendb01' at 94c010>
```

How do I tell if the connections are the same ?

Answer (score 3):

I've long found `weakref.proxy`'s design and implementation to be somewhat shaky. Witness...:

```
>>> import weakref
>>> ob=set(range(23))
>>> rob=weakref.proxy(ob)
>>> rob==ob
False
>>> rob.__eq__(ob)
True
```

...DEFINITELY peculiar!  In practice what I use from `weakref` are weak-key or sometimes weak-value dictionaries; but `weakref.ref` is sounder than the proxy wrapper on top of it:

```
>>> wr=weakref.ref(ob)
>>> wr()==ob
True
```

The need to "call" the ref to get the object (or None if the object has since disappeared) unfortunately makes it non-transparent (so a DB API module couldn't do it while staying compliant to the API). I don't understand why MySqlDb wants weak cursor->connection referencing at all, but if they do I see why they felt they had to use proxies rather than refs. However, one pays a very high price for that transparency!

Btw, the "explicit `__eq__`" trick (or an equivalent one with `__cmp__`, depending on the type of the underlying object) may help you, even though it's definitely inelegant!

Comment: I always thought that proxy pulls some very ugly abstraction breaking magic behind the scenes to avoid having to call a function like ref. Now I know for sure.

Comment: Your "particular" comparison results are because set.__eq__ doesn't know about proxies.  It sees that the other object isn't a set, so it returns False.  rob.__eq__ ends up being proxied from ob.__eq__, so it works in that direction.

It's a wart without a good solution.  (The options are to either have set and every other type check for instances of weakref.proxy, or have the python interpreter transparently replace it before calling __eq__ etc.)

Comment: @Matthew: not quite, `rob==ob` and `ob==rob` are both false (though `rob.__eq__(ob)` and `ob.__eq__(rob)`  do behave as you indicate). It's quite possible there's no good way to make a sufficiently transparent proxy, I'm just unhappy we tried in the first place!-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the non proxy with weakref.proxy and use the identity operator:

```
>>> interactive.cursor.connection is weakref.proxy(interactive.web_logic.conns.primary)
True
```

Calling weakref.proxy() twice will return the same proxy object.

Comment: That's sort of ugly.  You'd also have to do it on both sides, too, if you don't want to assume either side is a proxy.  I suppose this will work in some obscure cases where obj.__dict__ is being assigned to something else (eg. multiple objects share a __dict__), but in most cases I'd still stick to just comparing __dict__.

Comment: That's a pretty cool hack actually. 
Guess I COULD go around converting all operands to weakref.proxy before comparing. Makes weakref.proxy kinda of a virus that infects your whole application......

Comment: Also, it assumes that this behavior is guaranteed.  It has the feel of an optimization that you shouldn't depend on, since I don't see the behavior mentioned in the docs.  It's probably reasonably safe, but if you end up using this in your code a lot and the assumption is broken later on, it may become a difficult-to-fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is a standard weakref, you need to call it to get the object itself.

```
import weakref
class Test(object): pass
a = Test()
b = weakref.ref(a)
a is b() # True
a == b() # True
```

Using weakrefs here seems wrong, though: if I construct a connection, create a cursor from it, and discard the connection object, the cursor should remain valid.  There shouldn't be a circular dependency unless the connection is keeping a list of all cursors, in which case *that* is what should be the weakref.

Comment: it's a weakproxy, not a weakref.
Perhaps a weakness in the weakproxy implementation ?

Comment: Oh, you mean weakref.proxy (not "weakproxy", at least not in the Python standard lib).  That doesn't seem to expose any method to retrieve the original object, which seems like a major limitation of the type.  It must be an oversight; this limitation seems completely unnecessary.  There doesn't even seem to be any way to find out if an object is a proxy (short of trying to parse obj.__str__()).  This type doesn't seem very fully fleshed-out.

Comment: That said, try "obj1.__dict__ is obj2.__dict__".  ("You may only post one comment every 30 seconds."  This site is occasionally irritating.)

Comment: Yeah i got 'weakproxy' from the str representation and from reading the c code. But it appears that weakref.proxy is the only way to actually create it.